# PostgreSQL: How can my C (libpq) program detect which table constraint triggered error?

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I am trying to programmatically migrate a large dataset from an old MySQL database to PostgreSQL. The source data is a mess, so my pgsql tables have a bunch of constraints to catch bad data going in.

When an insert fails because of one of these constraints, how does my C program discover which constraint prevented the insert?

For example, one of the simpler tables looks like:

```
create table glue (
    product_id int not null references product(id),
    history_id int not null references history(id),
    constraint glue_idx unique (product_id,history_id)
);
```

Now, my program ends up executing an insert that triggers one of the constraints, PQresultStatus only tells me PGRES_FATAL_ERROR, and PQerrorMessage tells me:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "glue_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (product_id, history_id)=(413, 1762) already exists.
```

which is perfectly readable to me, a human. My question is, how can my C program discern that the error was caught by the glue_idx constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function

```
char *PQresultErrorField(const PGresult *res, int fieldcode)
```

which returns detailed information depending on `fieldcode`. One of possible codes is `PG_DIAG_CONSTRAINT_NAME`.

Find the function description in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-MAIN)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. For whatever reason, PG_DIAG_CONSTRAINT_NAME was undefined, but that was not hard to overcome. I just needed a pointer to the right function.

Comment: `PG_DIAG_CONSTRAINT_NAME` was introduced in Postgres 9.3.